# экранирование кавычек typehead yii2

Tags: yii2

использую typehead в yii2.
вот код

```
 echo Typeahead::widget([
                        'name' => 'search',
                        'value'=>(Yii::$app->request->get('search') ? Yii::$app->request->get('search') : ''),
                        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Поиск'],
                        'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
                        'dataset' => [
                            [
                                'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                                'display' => 'value',
                                'remote' => [
                                    'url' => Url::to(['/site/country-list']) . '?q=%QUERY',
                                    'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]);
```

Возвращается ответ в Json и все отображается, однако двойные кавычки он экранирует и показывает как &q u o t e;
Есть ли как то выход?

Answer (score 2):

Сам виджет двойные кавычки не экранирует. Возможно, вы это делаете когда готовите ответ сервера? Покажите какой ответ приходит в браузер через xhr.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделайте временную заглушку в виде

```
public function actionCountryList($q)
{
    return json_encode([['value' => 'aaa'], ['value' => '"bbb"']]);
}
```

и посмотрите что возвращается. Не забудьте добавить 'cache' => false в remote.